# Avoid putting PostgreSQL function result into one field

Tags: postgresql

The end result of what I am after is a query that calls a function and that function returns a set of records that are in their own separate fields. I can do this but the results of the function are all in one field.
ie: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETLCL.png and the results I am after are: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqRQ9.png

Here's the code to create the table

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_1_hm
(
tbl_1_hm_id bigserial NOT NULL,
tbl_1_hm_f1 VARCHAR (250),
tbl_1_hm_f2 INTEGER,
CONSTRAINT tbl_1_hm PRIMARY KEY (tbl_1_hm_id)   
)

-- do that for a few times to get some data
INSERT INTO tbl_1_hm (tbl_1_hm_f1, tbl_1_hm_f2)
VALUES ('hello', 1);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION proc_1_hm(id BIGINT)
RETURNS TABLE(tbl_1_hm_f1 VARCHAR (250), tbl_1_hm_f2 int AS $$
  SELECT tbl_1_hm_f1, tbl_1_hm_f2
  FROM tbl_1_hm 
  WHERE tbl_1_hm_id = id
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

--And here is the current query I am running for my results:
SELECT t1.tbl_1_hm_id, proc_1_hm(t1.tbl_1_hm_id) AS t3
FROM tbl_1_hm AS t1
```

Thanks for having a read. Please if you want to haggle about the semantics of what I am doing by hitting the same table twice or my naming convention --> this is a simplified test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a function returns a set of records, you should treat it as a table source:

```
SELECT t1.tbl_1_hm_id, t3.*
FROM tbl_1_hm AS t1, proc_1_hm(t1.tbl_1_hm_id) AS t3;
```

Note that [functions are implicitly using a `LATERAL` join](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM) (scroll down to sub-sections 4 and 5) so you can use fields from tables listed previously without having to specify an explicit `JOIN` condition.

Comment: FYI, if you want to return a *single row* with multiple fields, you can use `OUT` parameters and `RETURNS RECORD` instead. `RETURNS TABLE` is equivalent to using `OUT` parameters with `RETURNS SETOF RECORD`, i.e. it returns a row set. This makes it slower to call and limits where you can call it. I think you're actually wanting to return a set here, though, so never mind me.